# Haskell: wrap everything in list of lists as a list of lists of one element

Tags: list, haskell, sublist

Good day everyone.

What I am trying to accomplish is to convert a list like 
`[ [1, 2, 3], [25, 24, 23, 22], [13] ]` into `[ [1], [2], [3], [25], [24], [23], [22], [13] ]`.

I tried something like

```
reWrap :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
reWrap data = map (map (:[])) data
```

but of course it just wrapped the contents even deeper into brackets. I'm new into functional programming so any help or tip would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try replacing the first `map` with `concatMap` (which is `concat (map f)`) to get rid of the extra nesting.

Comment: `map return . concat` ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite easy, if you use the `concatMap` prelude function:

```
λ> :t concatMap
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
```

What `concatMap` does is `map` a function, then `concat` the resulting lists.

If we use this definition, we can get the desired effect:

```
solution :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
solution = concatMap (map (:[]))
```

Here it is in action:

```
λ> solution [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]]
λ> solution [[1,2,3],[],[12,19]]
[[1],[2],[3],[12],[19]]
```

---

As @amalloy said, the `>>=` function in the case of lists is equivalent to `flip concatMap`, so you could say this:

```
solution = (=<<) (map (:[]))
```

Comment: if you went with pointed style you could get rid of a few sets of parens: `solution xs = xs =<< map (:[])`, or perhaps even `solution xs = map (:[]) >>= xs`

Comment: It worked! (of course it did). Thanks to you and Xeo since he proposed the same answer in comments. It even gets rid of empty lists so this simple solution is perfect for my task.

Answer (score 6):

This is clearly a case for good old list comprehension:

```
 rewrap xss = [ [x] | xs <- xss, x <- xs ]
```

Comment: Oh, that's a nice one! Though I guess this is just an abstraction of `concatMap` or `>>=` like any other.

Comment: It is probably the same code like yours, once desugared, though easier to read for a beginer.

Comment: @Ingo not only for a beginner ;)

Answer (score 4):

first you need to concat the list

this `[ [1, 2, 3], [25, 24, 23, 22], [13] ]`
becomes `[1,2,3,25,24,23,22,13]`

then you need to wrap each element in a list

`reWrap = map (:[]) . concat`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps `reWrap = (>>= map return)`? But this is probably too abstruse for a beginner. There is a solution very close to the one you were trying: `rewrap xs = concat $ map (map (:[])) xs`. Note that your output was very close to what you wanted, except that everything was exactly one level too deep in a list; `concat` takes a list of lists and flattens it.

My solution is really doing the same thing, just with more shorthand. Specifically, `(:[])` is just `return` specialized to lists, and `concat $ map f xs` is the same as `xs >>= f` for lists. Then I also removed the explicit `xs` argument, since all you do with it is pass it to the partially-applied function you're really defining.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive version, not the shortest, yet that illustrates the wrapping of each item in each nested list, and that concatenates wrapped nested lists,

```
reWrap :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
reWrap [] = [[]]
reWrap (xs:xss) = (map (:[]) xs) ++ reWrap xss
```